# Why can't I use join() before closing pool in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a class that has a method that does some parallel calculations and is called pretty often. As such I want my pool to be initialized once, at the class's constructor and not create a new pool every time this method is called. In this method, I want to use apply_async() to start a task for all worker processes and then wait (block) and aggregate the result of each task. My code looks like this:

```
class Foo:
     def __init__(self, ...):
         # ...
         self.pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

     def do_parallel_calculations(self, ...):
         for _ in range(mp.cpu_count()):
              self.pool.apply_async(calc_func, args=(...), callback=aggregate_result)
         
         # wait for results to be aggregated to a global var by the callback
         self.pool.join()  # <-- ValueError: Pool is still running
         
         # do something with the aggregated result of all worker processes
```

However, when I run this I get an error in self.pool.join() that says: "ValueError: Pool is still running". Now, in all examples I have seen self.pool.close() is called before self.pool.join() and I assume that is why I get this error but I don't want to close my pool as I want it there for the next time this method is called! I can't not use self.pool.join() as I need a way to wait for all processes to finish and I don't want to wastefully spin manually for example by using a "while not global_flag: pass".

What can I do to achieve what I am trying to do? And why won't multiprocessing let me join with a still open pool? It seems like a perfectly reasonable thing to want to do.

Comment: You can't join a running pool. So, you close and join it, then create a new one. That's one of the prices of multiprocessing. Or you don't use async operations in the first place, which has a different price tag on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to do it by calling get() on the AsyncResult object that apply_async() returns. So the code becomes:

```
def do_parallel_calculations(self, ...):
     results = []
     for _ in range(mp.cpu_count()):
          results.append(self.pool.apply_async(calc_func, args=(...)))
     aggregated_result = 0
     for result in results:
          aggregated_result += result.get()
```

where calc_func() returns the individual task result and no callback and global variables are needed.

It's not ideal because I wait on them in an arbitrary order and not in the order that they actually finished (the most efficient way to do this would be to reduce the result) but since I only have 4 cores it should hardly be noticeable.

Comment: You are waiting on them in the order in which they are submitted. But as long as you are waiting for all of them to complete before continuing, this is not measurably slower than waiting on the order of completion even assuming the first one submitted is the last one completed: After you get the first result, the results for the other tasks will be available and the excess time spent that could have been saved by getting the results in completion order is just the time it takes for the repeated calls `result.get()`, which return immediately, plus the time for aggregating the results.

Answer (score 2):

Let's make this concrete with a real example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def calc_func(x):
    return x * x


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    def do_parallel_calculations(self, values):
        results = []
        for value in values:
            results.append(self.pool.apply_async(calc_func, args=(value,)))
        for result in results:
            print(result.get())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    foo.do_parallel_calculations([1,2,3])
```

Comment: I guess you realized the same solution, more or less as I was developing my answer.